# Does LibreOffice work on OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, libreoffice

I rely heavily on LibreOffice and am hesitant to upgrade unless I can be as sure as possible that LibreOffice (Writer) will run.

Can anybody confirm that the software works and does not crash on Mavericks?

Answer (score 3):

It did not crash with OS X Mavericks, but it does not work at all. I received a message that this OS is not compatible with Libre Office.

Comment: I constantly get a message that it wants to restore old documents, which won't disappear. Also, Hotkeys (even cmd-A) won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I am having no problem at all running LibreOffice Version: 4.1.2.3 on Mavericks. I got no such message as @Wil

Comment: I can second that! No Problems running it.

Comment: Same here. No issues. Even Add-Ons work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to override your security settings and open the app anyway.

1. In the Finder, locate the app you want to open. Most apps can be found in the `/Applications` folder.
2. Right-click or <kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd>-click the app icon.
3. Choose Open from the shortcut menu.
4. Click Open on the Gatekeeper popup.

The app is saved as an exception to your security settings, and you will be able to open it in the future by double-clicking it, just like any authorized app.

Answer (score 0):

On Mavericks, an ods spreadsheet file (version 4.1.4) used to close on its own when it was within a folder. I moved the file to the desktop and now have no problems using it